# Coefficients of the Chern connection form of the tautological line bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Following [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041234/connection-on-tautological-bundle-over-mathbbcp1), I would like to compute the coefficients of the connection form of the Chern connection of $\gamma^n$, the tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^n$, with respect to the natural Hermitian metric.

Given that $\gamma^n \subset \mathbb{C}P^n \times \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, we can induce the metric from the standard Hermitian metric (dot product) on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, where if $(p,v_i) \in \gamma^n$, then $h( (p,v_1), (p,v_2)) = v_1 \cdot v_2$.

Let $\nabla$ be the Chern connecion of $h$ over $\gamma^n$. How would I go about finding the connection form coefficients of $\nabla$?

From the linked question, I know that, locally, the connection form is $\frac{\bar{z} dz}{1+ |z|^2}$. But I do not know how to extract the coefficients from this, unless I'm missing the obvious.

**EDIT:** Perhaps to rephrase and clarify my question:

> Given the Chern connection of the tautological bundle, what are its connection coefficients/Christoffel symbols?

Are they just $\frac{\bar{z}_k}{1+|z|^2}$ where $z = (z_1, \ldots, z_n)$ are local coordinates?

Comment: Since $\gamma^n$ is a line bundle and the connection is compatible with the complex structure, local expressions for the connection form will be given by  one forms valued in endomorphisms of the complex line $\gamma^n$. Since the endomorphisms of a line are given by $\mathbb{C}$, we can identify the connection form with a complex valued form as is done implicitly in the question you have linked.

Comment: What do you mean by coefficients? The connection form is a skew-hermitian $1\times 1$ matrix, i.e., a pure imaginary $1$-form.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter Thanks, I guess I'm just confused about how to explicitly find the coefficient(s), would it just be $\frac{\bar{z}}{1+|z|^2}$ in this case?

Comment: @TedShifrin By that I mean for a general vector bundle, we get a matrix of functions, if I understand correctly, giving information about the connection form. For example, for an affine connection, these are just the Christoffel symbols, so I'm looking for these "symbols" in the case of the tautological bundle, if that makes sense

Comment: The linked question gives you the connection form for $n=1$ (in the $z$-chart). In general, you have $\omega([Z]) = \partial\log \|Z\|^2$. Again, this is a $1\times 1$ matrix, so it's one $1$-form.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found a way to get the connection coefficients/Christoffel symbols. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Given the Chern connection $\nabla$ on $\gamma^n$, the bundle is a complex line bundle, so a rank $2$ real vector bundle, over a complex manifold of real dimension $2n$. I am using the real rank and dimension in order to count the Christoffel symbols properly, since they will be real functions.

So let $e_1, e_2$ be a (real) local frame for $\gamma^n$, $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ holomorphic local coordinates. I will split them as $z_k = x_k + i y_k$.

We have $\nabla e_1 = \omega_{1}^1 \otimes e_1 + \omega_{1}^2 \otimes e_2$ and $\nabla e_2 = \omega_{2}^1 \otimes e_1 + \omega_{2}^2 \otimes e_2$, where $\omega_{i}^{j}$ are the connection $1$-forms.

Now, we plug in the local basis vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y^k}$ and get $\nabla_{\partial x^k} e_1 = \omega_{1}^1 (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k})e_1 + \omega_{1}^2 (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k})e_2$, etc. where $\omega_{i}^{j} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}), \omega_{i}^{j} (\frac{\partial}{\partial y^k})$ are the connection coefficients/Christoffel symbols of $\nabla$. My count gives $8n$ coefficients.

Since in the holomorphic case we get the (complex) connection $1$-form to be $\frac{\bar{z}_k dz^k}{1+|z|^2}$ (Einstein summation), using the splitting $z_k = x_k + i y_k$ should naturally give the four real $1$-forms $$\omega_{1}^1 = \frac{x_k dx^k}{1+ |z|^2}, \omega_{1}^2 = \frac{x_k dy^k}{1+ |z|^2}, \omega_{2}^1 = -\frac{y_k dx^k}{1+ |z|^2}, \omega_{2}^2 = \frac{y_k dy^k}{1+ |z|^2}.$$

And thus, the $8n$ connection coefficients/Christoffel symbols should just be

\begin{align}
\omega_{1}^1 (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}) &= \frac{x_k}{1+ |z|^2},\\
\omega_{1}^1 (\frac{\partial}{\partial y^k}) &= 0,\\
\omega_{1}^2 (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}) &= 0,\\
\omega_{1}^2 (\frac{\partial}{\partial y^k}) &= \frac{x_k}{1+ |z|^2},\\
\omega_{2}^1 (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}) &= -\frac{y_k}{1+ |z|^2},\\
\omega_{2}^1 (\frac{\partial}{\partial y^k}) &= 0,\\
\omega_{2}^2 (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}) &= 0,\\
\omega_{2}^2 (\frac{\partial}{\partial y^k}) &= \frac{y_k}{1+ |z|^2}.
\end{align}

Does this work out?

Comment: This continues to be confused. You seem to refuse to think of the bundle as a hermitian complex line bundle, but prefer to think of it as a real $2$-plane bundle. Chern connections are defined explicitly on hermitian *holomorphic* complex bundles. But if you're thinking of $U(1)$ as $SO(2)$, then the connection matrix of the associated real bundle should be skew-symmetric. So I have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: @TedShifrin It's very likely that I am confusing many things. In the hopes of making things clear, here is the setup in my mind. The connection coefficients of an affine connection are the Christoffel symbols, which are real functions, whether the bundle is real or complex. So I'm assuming one can find the connection coefficients of an arbitrary real/complex bundle, also real functions. I'm looking for the connection coefficients of this particular Chern connection on the tautological bundle. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you think these are real functions if you're working with a complex (in particular, holomorphic) vector bundle? Again, the Chern forms are defined only for *complex* vector bundles, not for real bundles.

Comment: @TedShifrin Assuming that they are real must be one of my mistakes. Maybe explaining my motivation will help. Let $f: S^2 \to \mathbb{CP}^n$ for $n$ large enough be a map that classifies the tangent bundle of $S^2$ (thinking of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ as a complex Grassmannian). I want to pullback the Chern connection $\nabla$ on $\gamma^n$ to obtain a connection $f^* \nabla$ on $TS^2$, and I want to compute the Christoffel symbols of this new connection. This is why I'm focusing on the "real" side of things, because I want Christoffel symbols as real functions.

Comment: Two points. First, the classifying map pulls back *complex* line bundles, so I don't know why you want to pass to real bundles. Second, do you have any earthly idea what this classifying map actually is?

Comment: @TedShifrin 1. I'm assuming that a connection on a complex line bundle that happens to be the tangent bundle of manifold admits Christoffel symbols that are real. 2. I have no idea what the map $f$ actually is, I just want the Christoffel symbols to be expressed in terms of $f$

Comment: I can tell you the classifying map by using basic complex geometry. You embed $\Bbb CP^1$ as a conic in $\Bbb CP^2$ with the conjugate complex structure. Then the unitary connection form is just the complex conjugate (i.e., the negative). Your issue with real Christoffel symbols is a big deal about nothing. You need to understand that $SO(2)=U(1)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the explanation, this will be useful if I need to construct $f$ explicitly. Nevertheless, my goal is to obtain the (real) Christoffel symbols in terms of $f$. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your point about $SO(2) = U(1)$, will this be helpful in finding them? Otherwise, how do I go about finding the Christoffel symbols in terms of $f$?

Comment: If you actually work out the Chern connection, there is a single pure-imaginary $1$ form, as I said ages ago. You take $\omega=\partial\log\|Z\|^2$ and work with it as a complex form, pull it back by $f$. You can then rewrite the pullback $f^*\omega$ on $S^2$ as a combination of $dz$ and $d\bar z$ and turn that into Christoffel symbols in your preferred local coordinate system.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah thank you! that makes a lot more sense than what I was thinking. I was complicating my life by trying to force real coefficients for the Chern connection I guess. I'll do what you suggest and update my answer above accordingly. Thanks!