# Compute first Chern class for complex Torus

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

I have developed a keen interest in understanding the Calabi-Yau manifold. I have been following **"Lectures on Kähler Geometry" by Andrei Moroianu** and several online resources. However, it seems that I have become lost in the details, particularly when trying to comprehend the computation of the Chern class. It has been rather unintuitive for me thus far.

> Proposition 16.1. To every complex vector bundle $E$ over a smooth manifold $M$ one can associate a cohomology class $c_1(E) \in H^2(M, \mathbb{Z})$ called the first Chern class of $E$ satisfying the following axioms:
> (1) Naturality: For every smooth map $f: M \rightarrow N$ and complex vector bundle $E$ over $N$, one has $f^*\left(c_1(E)\right)=c_1\left(f^* E\right)$, where the left term denotes the pull-back in cohomology and $f^* E$ is the pull-back bundle defined by $f^* E_x=E_{f(x)}, \forall x \in M$.
> (2) Whitney sum formula: For every bundles $E, F$ over $M$ one has $c_1(E \oplus F)=c_1(E)+c_1(F)$, where $E \oplus F$ is the Whitney sum defined as the pull-back of the bundle $E \times F \rightarrow M \times M$ by the diagonal inclusion of $M$ in $M \times M$.
> (3) Normalization: The first Chern class of the tautological bundle of $\mathbb{C P}^1$ is equal to -1 in $H^2\left(\mathbb{C P}^1, \mathbb{Z}\right) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$, which means that the integral over $\mathbb{C P}^1$ of any representative of this class equals -1 .

Another one,

> Let $E$ be a complex vector bundle over a manifold $M$, and let $F=dA+A\land A$ be the curvature two-form of a connection $A$ on $E$. We define the total chern class $c(E)=\det(1+\frac{i}{2\pi}E)=1+c_1(E)+\cdots$ where $c_k(E)\in H^{2k}(M,\mathbb R)$.

To overcome this challenge, I have decided to narrow my focus and study a single particular example in order to gain a more comprehensive understanding and motivation (like study only that part which is needed in this process otherwise it's seemed I will never complete the goal). Specifically, I am planning to work with the complex torus. My objective is to demonstrate that the complex torus possesses Kähler metrics with a vanishing first Chern class.

Unfortunately, I have been unable to find a single resource that provides a detailed explanation of these concepts for a complex torus. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could suggest a resource that covers these aspects thoroughly. Thank you in advance. TIA

Comment: Which definition of Chern classes are you using?

Comment: I have added two definitions that I came across so far. @ArcticChar

Comment: Try the second one. You can use whatever connection you have. Of course use the simplest one (which is possible since the complex torus has trivial tangent bundle).

Comment: Okay, $T\mathbb T=T(\mathbb S\times \mathbb S)\cong T(\mathbb S)\times T(\mathbb S)$ then I guess it should be $\mathbb S\times \mathbb R\times \mathbb S\times \mathbb R$. But to be honest I couldn't manage to understand the computation of chern class. Like every resource I read only mention it with abstract definition. I guess getting a example can give me some insight. As I read all of these material by self study, things are still not super clear to me. @ArcticChar

Comment: A characteristic class lives in the cohomology of the base. If the cohomology of the base is trivial, for example if the base is a point, then the characteristic class vanishes. Any trivial bundle over any base can be viewed as the pullback by the terminal map from the base to a point. Therefore any characteristic class of a trivial bundle vanishes by the naturality axiom. And the tangent bundle of the torus is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ziggurism Can you suggest any reference for non-trivial one? Actually, I want to see the computation.

Comment: The simplest nontrivial bundle to compute the first chern class of is the tautological bundle on $\mathbb{C}P^1$. This is actually a pretty good exercise to do, to get your hands on things. Then you can integrate it to get the chern number. I don’t have a reference, since the text I have in mind (Milnor & Stasheff) assigns this as homework if I recall.

Comment: But of course this only makes sense to do if you are using a geometric definition of character class. In the axiomatic definition you gave above, $c_1(\gamma_{\mathbb{C}P^1})$ is taken as an axiom. In that case, the next chern class to work out is the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{C}P^1$. There is a nice relationship between the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ in terms of sums of the tautological bundle $\gamma_{\mathbb{C}P^n}$ which allows you to work out the chern class of the bundle

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2041234/16490

Comment: It seems there are a lot of definition to show calabi-yau manifold. Like using connection on vector bundle, tangent bundle is canonical, vanishing Ricci curvature etc. I think showing zero Ricci form is comparatively good way to tackle this. Can you suggest any good resource on that? @ziggurism and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to make use of Chern--Weil theory, then one can proceed as follows: A complex torus is a quotient of $\mathbf{C}^n$ by a lattice $\Lambda$ of maximal rank. The Euclidean metric $\omega_{\delta}$ on $\mathbf{C}^n$ is flat, Kähler, and invariant under translations. Hence, $\mathbf{T}^n = \mathbf{C}^n/ \Lambda$ admits a flat Kähler metric; in particular, its Ricci curvature vanishes identically $\text{Ric}(\omega_{\delta}) =0$.

The first Chern class $c_1(X) : = c_1(-K_X)$ is represented by $1/2\pi$ times the Ricci curvature of a Kähler metric. Hence, $$c_1(\mathbf{T}^n) = c_1(-K_{\mathbf{T}^n}) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \{ \text{Ric}(\omega_{\delta}) \} = 0.$$

Comment: Great(+1)! It really seems like that calculating Chern class from bundle connection is complicated. I was wondering can you mention the kähler metric explicitly? Because I couldn't come up with that. @KyleBroder I want to verify $\text Ric(g)=0$

Comment: @N00BMaster If the metric is Hermitian but not Kähler, I need to be more careful with what is meant by "Ricci curvature". Indeed, the Levi-Civita connection and Chern connection are distinct, and due to the presence of torsion in the Chern connection, there are four distinct "Chern Ricci curvatures". The Ricci curvature that is being used here is the "first Chern Ricci curvature" given by tracing the Chern curvature tensor over the third and fourth indices (i.e., over the endomorphism part).

Comment: @N00BMaster I think I misinterpreted your question. Upon rereading your question, I'm not sure what you're asking. What I wrote above shows that $\text{Ric}(\omega_{\delta}) =0$.

Comment: It seems that you have no idea how to calculate the Chern class given a metric, @N00BMaster. It seems that you don't even have the formula with you. Can you find it in the book?

Comment: I didn't find anything like that in the lecture notes or books I have right now. In fact, I couldn't find any examples of computations for Ricci forms or curvature. @ArcticChar

Comment: See the discussion starting at p.56 in "Lectures on Kähler Geometry" by Andrei Moroianu. Also formula (9) in the book. @N00BMaster